# I faced the problem that a chapter is divided into two sub-chapters

Tags: numbering, chapters

I'm typesetting a Ph.D.-thesis and one of the chapters separates into two sub-chapters so I need it to count chapters like that:

```
1. Chapter one

2a. Chapter two A

2b. Chapter two B

3. Chapter three
```

Here problem that if we use following comment :

```
***********************************************************

\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

%\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref

\newcounter{subchapter}\renewcommand{\thesubchapter}{\alph{subchapter}}
\makeatletter

% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\newcommand{\updatechaptercounter}{}

\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\@afterheading}{\updatechaptercounter\@afterheading}{}{}% Regular patch of \@chapter

%\patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}{\@afterheading}{\updatechaptercounter\@afterheading}{}{}% Hyperref patch of \@chapter

\makeatother

\providecommand{\theHchapter}{}%

\newcommand{\startsubchapters}{%

  \setcounter{subchapter}{0}% Reset sub-chapter numbering

  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}\thesubchapter}% Update chapter number display

  \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\arabic{chapter}\thesubchapter}% Update chapter number display (for hyperref)

  \renewcommand{\updatechaptercounter}{\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}}% Update chapter number

  \let\oldchapter\chapter%
  \renewcommand{\chapter}{\stepcounter{subchapter}\oldchapter}% Increment subchapter
}
\newcommand{\stopsubchapters}{%

  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}% Reset chapter numbering

  \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\arabic{chapter}}% Reset chapter numbering (for hyperref)

  \let\chapter\oldchapter% Restore regular \chapter command

  \renewcommand{\updatechaptercounter}{}% Clear chapter counter update

  \stepcounter{chapter}% Update chapter counter

}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter one}

\startsubchapters

\chapter{chapter 2 A}

\chapter{chapter 2 B}

\stopsubchapters

\chapter{chapter three}

********************************************************************************
```

Respected Teachers/Friends

By using above text in LaTex, we have chapters contents are

```
1. Chapter one

2a. Chapter two A

3b. Chapter three B

4. chapter 4
```

Please solve this problem.

Comment: What document class are you using? I cannot reproduce your scenario, I always get an error that some stuff is undefined. Please provide a complete MWE. Anyway, could you try doing `\global\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}` instead of just `\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}`?

Comment: This code works very fine for me, there is no probleme.